# Performing an Android network operation on a background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

At the moment I use an Android OS Handler that runs for 3 seconds. The problem is I don't know how long the network operation will actually take. Is there a way to stop the progress dialog only when the 200 messages have been deleted?

**Handler:**

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                        () -> {
                            // On complete call delete contact method
                            deleteAllMsgs(progressDialog);
                            // onLoginFailed();
                        }, 3000);
```

**Method:**

```
private void deleteAllMsgs(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> msgQuery= new ParseQuery<>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGE);
        // Query the Comment class for comments that have a "author" column value equal to the objectId of the current User
        msgQuery.whereEqualTo((ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_AUTHOR_POINTER), ParseUser.msgQuery());
        yeetQuery.setLimit(200);
        msgQuery.findInBackground((messages, e) -> {
            if (e == null) {
                // Iterate over all messages
                for (ParseObject delete : messages) {

                    // Delete messages from local data store
                    try {
                        delete.unpin();
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Delete messages from Parse
                    delete.deleteInBackground();

                }

                // Return to main screen
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "200 messages deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();


            } else {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ParseQuery already runs in a separate thread

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah but the progress dialog doesn't, and I wan't to sync it with the delete in background method.

Comment: Then you need to use the DeleteCallback that Parse provides and dismiss within in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
progress.setTitle("In Progress");
progress.show();

AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do things.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Update UI.
                    }
                });
                //Do things.
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

progress.setOnDismissListener(newDialogInterface.OnDismissListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //Called after your background task ended.
            }
        });
```

You can use runOnUiThread method as much as you want in asynctask method. With that you can send toast message, set text of a textview etc...

Comment: If I put ``progressDialog.show();`` in runOnUiThread, when do I cancel it?

Comment: Everything is synchronized in asynctask.execute runnable. So you can cancel progressdialog at the end of runnable code. And you can set a progressDialog cancel listener out of asynctask.execute runnable.

Comment: I edit my answer with example. If this what you are looking for, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using OS handler, you have to go with Asynch task methodology, reference here https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar.

Here not necessarily to use "progressUpdate()", without that you can also do that.

So you can put initialisation of progressdialog in "preExecute()",

then put  your "deleteAllMessage()" in doInBackguound() and

when task completed it will automatically jump to "postExecute()".

So there you can stop showing progress bar. By calling:

```
    progressdialog.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to stop the progress dialog only when the 200 messages have been deleted?

Yes, you need to use the callback from Parse correctly.

Put your "after messages deleted" code **immediately after** the for loop over the messages instead of outside the callback

And you don't need a Handler or Asynctask for ParseQuery.findInBackground or deleteInBackground

Besides, you should be using `deleteAllInBackground(List<T> objects, DeleteCallback callback)` with a callback to know when a list of objects is deleted rather than having to find them first

Comment: ``Put your "after messages deleted" code immediately after the for loop over the messages instead of outside the callback`` Isn't that already the case?

Comment: No, it's outside of the callback. You're not waiting for the messages to be deleted to dismiss anything